# Cross account role granting S3 bucket access - Permission Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam

I have two accounts, account ACCOUNTAAAA, and ACCOUNTBBBB. A bucket (BUCKETAAAA) exists in account ACCOUNTAAAA and an instance with a role (ROLEBBBB) in ACCOUNTBBBB needs to be able to read from it.

I have adding the following permissions to the bucket:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTBBBB:role/ROLEBBBB"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETAAAA/*"
    }
```

I have the following permissions on the role in `ACOUNTBBBB`:

```
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETAAAA/",
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETAAAA/*"
        ]
    }
```

My assumption is I should be able to run `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKETAAAA` on the EC2 instance with the IAM role attached, and see the contants of BUCKETAAAA. When I try this, I get `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes thank you, I have corrected that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created **Role-B** in Account-B with EC2 as the Trusted Entity *("Allows EC2 instances to call AWS services on your behalf")* and a policy granting access to Bucket-A
- Created **Bucket-A** in Account-A
- Added a **Bucket Policy** to Bucket-A, which grants access to Role-B
- Assigned **Role-B** to an Amazon EC2 instance

The **Bucket Policy** on Bucket-A was:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/role-b"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The permissions on Role-B were:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BucketA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was able to **successfully** use `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-a` and was able to copy files to Bucket-A.

The main difference I see with your attempt was that your Bucket Policy only granted permissions for:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETAAAA/*"
```

This means "anything within Bucket-A" but does *not* include Bucket-A itself. The command `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKETAAAA` operates on the **bucket**, for which the role has no permissions.

Thus, you should also add permissions for the bucket itself:

```
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETAAAA",
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETAAAA/*"
```

Comment: I assume in your first code block, the principle should be role-b?

Comment: Oops! Fixed! (I used other role names.)